# Visual studio requires new version of windows to display the content. Please update UAP or later

Tags: c#, uwp

Facing this issue while creating UWP App. I downloaded all updates from windows and in VS2017, but still could not resolve this error:

> Visual studio requires new version of windows to display the content. Please update UAP or later

Comment: https://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/tcmva/forum/tcmvacoursefdbk-tcmvavisual-course_42281/please-update-to-uap-100150630/bf14f511-e33e-4790-b295-25e67af0880c?auth=1 souns like a similiar issue

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 what does it mean then? How am I supposed to get a new version otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the similar issue in MSDN, and it has an accepted answer you could refer to.

> please install the latest windows updates. You can check / install updates through the windows update area inside the settings. You can also get the exact version of windows 10 that you are using at the moment inside the settings (Click on System and then About).
>
> The min / target version are just for the end product. But if you installed the latest Updates for Visual Studio then Visual Studio wants to have the newest version, too. (And the (web)installer always installs the latest version e.g. the latest sdk which was released together with the aniversary update of Windows 10.)

This is original [case link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64ef706d-601d-4f6d-8abc-83b2f5306421/uwpvisual-studio-requires-newer-version-of-windows-to-display-the-content-please-update-windows?forum=wpdevelop).